# Delaying Switchery loading delay

Tags: javascript, switchery

I am using switchery js as button in my html page but when i am loading the page i can see the checkbox changing to button. It does not seems pretty good in UI. I think the issue is because of js processing delay as my project has many js files.

Comment: Hard to give an answer to this.

Comment: Slideon Solved my problem now 0 latency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think maybe you can use slideon, which is a similar component built for zero latency and is very lightweight with easy customization options.

Here is the git repo - https://github.com/shaheenhyderk/slideon

And documentaion- https://shaheenhyder.com/slideon

Hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, integrating slideon solved the issue

Comment: Yeah, Pretty good!